# Motivation of the solution of a graph theory problem

Tags: graph-theory

The problem is:
There is a math class with some students such that no matter what four students you choose there is always at least one that knows the other 3. (Note that knowing is symmetric, if A knows B then B knows A). Show that there is a student that knows everybody.

And the solution starts by showing that every student does not know at most 2 people... and after this the problem becomes almost trivial.

How can someone think about something like this?

Comment: Are you asking for a solution to the problem?

Comment: Well, when I see on TV people who runs 100 m in less than 10 seconds, I might ask the same question. But if the did in less than 15 seconds, I might still ask the same question.

Comment: Serious answers pls....

Comment: I just wanna know the motivation behind this

Comment: It's still unclear what you're trying to ask. It sounds like you have a solution key to the problem and understand the solution, but want to know how to make the leap from seeing the problem and coming up with the solution.

If so: the question of mathematical creativity is complicated, potentially impossible to satisfactorily answer, and probably outside the scope of this site. You might find the beginning of an answer in Pólya's classic book [*How To Solve It*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It).

Answer (score 0):

The beginning of a problem resolution, specially if the problem is somewhat difficult, often seems magic. Just like a supernatural being was giving clues to the person who solves it.

But this is not the truth, obviously. Behind this brilliant idea, there are always (or almost always, at least) many dead ways, many failed tries.

It's just like if you go to a unknown city and you ask for the Main Square. The peasant says you some perfect indications and, if you follow them, you arrive at your destiny. But, how could the peasant know that? The answer is simple: he knows his city, and he knows it because he has been walking in it for years.

Comment: You didnt answer at all, how can I think of doing that in the specific problem?